# Getting maps not to sort alphabetically

Tags: java, maps

Ok, so I've got a `Map<String, List<String>>` and I've tried to use HashMap (which doesn't sort it alphabetically, nor the way they were put in), and TreeMap, which sorts it alphabetically. I don't want that, I want it to sort it by when it was put in, so say if I added "a", then "c", then "b", I want it to be:

"a, c, b" NOT "a, b, c" when I loop the keys

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried? Your code would help provide an answer.

Comment: There aren't that many "Implementing Classes" listed for [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in the javadoc. With a minimum amount of research effort, you could have found the answer yourself.

Comment: Thing is, I did, but didn't find anything helpful ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `java.util.LinkedHashMap`.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key
>   is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if
>   m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true
>   immediately prior to the invocation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't accept your answer before in 10 minutes, will do so then.